# Does the Bing Maps AJAX control support all platforms?

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

I am start develop on Bing Map application using Ajax control api. Does this control supports for all platforms including mobile platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bing Maps AJAX v7.0 control is *officially* supported on the following browsers (it may also work on others):

- Internet Explorer 7/8/9 (PC)
- Firefox 3.6 + (PC/Mac)
- Safari 5 (Mac)
- Google Chrome (PC)
- Apple 3GS/4.0 iPhone Browser
- Google Android 2.X Browser
- BlackBerry 6.0 Browser

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427618.aspx